# How can we get table size in Salesforce using CData driver?

Tags: salesforce, cdata, salesforce-lightning, cdata-drivers

I want to fetch the size of my table in Salesforce using a CData driver.

Answer (score 0):

if you want number of rows, you can use the COUNT as follows:

```
select count(*) FROM Account
```